# Why is this single MDDataTable looking so bad in KivyMD?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I want to show a `MDDataTable` in a `MDScreen` in KivyMD, but it looks awful. This is the Python code:

```
class AddPlayerScreen(MDScreen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AddPlayerScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.app = MDApp.get_running_app()
        self.all_players_datatable = MDDataTable(
            # use_pagination=True,
            check=True,
            elevation=2,
            padding=0,
            background_color_header="#00ccff",
            column_data=[
                ('Name', dp(30)),
                ('Played', dp(12)),
                ('Wins', dp(10)),
                ('Rating', dp(12)),
                ('ID', dp(10)),
            ],
            row_data=[
                ('John Doe', 4, 2, '50%', 1),
                ('Jane Doe', 4, 2, '50%', 1),
            ],
        )
        self.ids.all_players_boxlayout.add_widget(self.all_players_datatable)
```

And this is the KV file:

```
<AddPlayerScreen>:

    MDBoxLayout:
        id: all_players_boxlayout
        orientation: 'vertical'
```

It is a very basic code, but when I run the app:

[image]

As you can see, the header checkbox, and the header name of the first column, are almost out of the first row. Why? I'm not able no change that. Besides that, is there a way to fit the columns to the size of the `MDDataTable`? If I expand the width of the window, the table looks even more awful. And I would like to reduce the spaces inside the table, like the padding, the distance between the header and the rows, and the height of the rows, but the padding property does nothing.

I'm facing a lot of errors of this type. In fact, I had to replace a `MDSelectionList` with this `MDDataTable` because `MDSelectionList` had errors too (if I selected a row and unselected it, I was not able to select it again...) Why? I'm using Python 3.8 and KivyMD 1.2.0.dev0.